# Flask python where should I put goods that go to cart in online shop?

Tags: python, session, python-3.x, flask

I am building a simple shop with flask and python 3.
I have table `goods` , and now I have simple question.
I don't have user registration, you can just buy goods without it.

So when I click button `add to cart` where should I put the id of selected good and its quantity?

If I had registration I could make another table where I could save `user_id` `good_id` and whatever I need.

But  in my case should I use some session scoped variable?
According to this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827764/ecommerceshopping-cartwhere-should-i-store-shopping-cart-data-in-session-or)  - yes.
So can you provide me an example of creating and modifying this session scope variable?
I tried to google google some links  like [this](http://code.runnable.com/Uhf58hcCo9RSAACs/using-sessions-in-flask-for-python)  but still unclear.

Comment: You could also assign the user a unique id and then use a table just as if you knew who the user is.  This would have the advantage of the shopping cart persisting between visits (ie shutting down browser).  You would also then require to do routine house cleaning (cleaning out old sessions from the database).  The only real difference between a known user and an anonymous user is that you know their name.  Use the session and/or the database depending on your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You should use flask Sessions. Please see the documentation:

Here is some example code:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort, session, flash, redirect, url_for

@store_blueprint.route('/product/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def product(id=0):
    # AddCart is a form from WTF forms. It has a prefix because there
    # is more than one form on the page. 
    cart = AddCart(prefix="cart")

    # This is the product being viewed on the page. 
    product = Product.query.get(id)


    if cart.validate_on_submit():
        # Checks to see if the user has already started a cart.
        if 'cart' in session:
            # If the product is not in the cart, then add it. 
            if not any(product.name in d for d in session['cart']):
                session['cart'].append({product.name: cart.quantity.data})

            # If the product is already in the cart, update the quantity
            elif any(product.name in d for d in session['cart']):
                for d in session['cart']:
                    d.update((k, cart.quantity.data) for k, v in d.items() if k == product.name)

        else:
            # In this block, the user has not started a cart, so we start it for them and add the product. 
            session['cart'] = [{product.name: cart.quantity.data}]


        return redirect(url_for('store.index'))
```

This is just a basic example.

Comment: That works great for me, thanks! I have just one question - why do you need `.format(id)` on creating the new cart?

Comment: That's actually not necessary and doesn't actually do anything. I should have removed that.